# Dual space of a topological vector space that doesn't separate points?

Tags: topological-vector-spaces, dual-spaces

While I am studying FUNCTIONAL ANALYSIS by Walter Rudin, I found the following corollary.

[image: Ruding FA, p60]

Now, I wonder how the dual space(the set of all continuous linear functionals on $X$) of some pathetic topological vector spaces can't separate the points.
Since a topological vector space (in this context) should be Hausdorff, if $X^*$ doesn't separate $x\neq y\in X,$ then $\forall f\in X^*$, there are disjoint open sets $G_x,\ G_y\subset X$ s.t. $x\in G_x,\ y\in G_y$ and $f(G_x)\cap f(G_y)\neq\emptyset$. (This is because if $f(x)\neq f(y)$, then we can find disjoint open sets $G_x, G_y$ s.t. $x\in G_x,\ y\in G_y$ and $f(G_x)\cap f(G_y)=\emptyset$.

At least finite dimensional topological vector space on $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$. So, to find an answer we should find an infinite dimensional case or change the scalar field to other fields such as the rational number field(?).

I thought of a situation where the cardinality of the topological vector space is too large that any continuous linear functional can't be onto. But still, I couldn't find the suitable example. For example, $l^p$ space is one of the non-locally convex spaces with larger cardinality than $\mathbb{R}$, but its dual space separates points on $l^p$.

Or in a pathetic topological vector space, the satisfying continuity is so difficult that only the zero functional is in $X^*$?  (I don't know how this is possible for infinite-dimensional topological vector space though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct term is "pathological topological vector space" rather than "pathetic topological vector space".

In any case, some topological vector spaces that are not locally convex can have dual space $\{0\}$.  A standard example is $L^p([0,1])$ when $0 < p < 1$. More generally, $L^p(X)^{*} = \{0\}$ when $0 < p < 1$ and $X$ is a nonatomic measure space. See Theorems 2.21 and 3.5 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/lpspace.pdf).

Comment: Oh, thanks. I misunderstood the case for l^p. when 0<p<1.

Comment: An $\ell^p$-space has atoms since it is $L^p(X)$ where $X$ is the natural numbers with counting measure.  Its dual space is *not* $\{0\}$: see Example 3.4 in the file I linked to.